# Logstash Grok Filter comma sep. string

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I just can't handle the following condition...

> Abschluß|NN   0.0040  Abschlüße,Abschlußs,Abschlußes,Abschlüßen
>
> Abstimmung|NN 0.0040  Abstimmungen
>
> Agilität|NN   0.0040

- How do I separate the comma-separated string into individual words?
  IF it exists AND has more than one word!?!?? @_@

I've got everything so far.

```
%{WORD:word}\|%{WORD:type}\t%{NUMBER:count}\t
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Germany for the beautiful special characters!

However, is there still a possibility to distribute this list into own fields depending on the number of elements?

```
(?<word>[A-Za-z0-9ÄÖÜäöüß]+)\|(?<type>[A-Za-z0-9ÄÖÜäöüß]+)\t%{NUMBER:count}(\t)?(?<list>[[A-Za-z0-9ÄÖÜäöüß]+\,]+)?
```